# How to use thread to call Native method in Opencv Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opencv, dlib

Everyone. I'm beginner for Android, as well as **Opencv Library**.   I want to call JNI method inside thread which should return Mat for `onCameraFrame()` of opencv. In jni I make use of dlib library to detect face. 
This is the sample code I have tried:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{
    mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
    outputMat=callThreadToDetect()
    return outputMat;
}

private Mat callThreadToDetect()
{
    Mat dispMat;
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        Imgproc.cvtColor( mRgba , inputMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
        NativeOpencv.detectHuman(inputMat.getNativeObjAddr(),outputMat.getNativeObjAddr());
        dispMat=outputMat.clone();
        }
    });
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dispMat;
}I
```

when I use above code outputMat/dispMat will not be returned to `onCameraFrame()`, view shows me black sceen. Please suggest me how to deal with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you run `NativeOpencv.detectHuman()` in the same thread that called `onCameraFrame()`?

Comment: I can run.. But to raise the fps I need to run the native method in the separate thread. It may help me. @nandsito

Comment: You can have look at the native code here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927923/dlib-android-detection-of-face-landmark-is-slow]

Comment: it is not clear for me if the problem is the black screen, or low fps, or both. What is the issue?

Comment: actually the main thread is waiting for the face detection thread with `t.join();`, so there is no parallelism yet. I suggest trying to run the face detection in the same thread, then ensure it is properly working (even in low fps), and only then paralellize the face detection

Comment: Okie.. I'll explain you what exactly the problem is.. I want to run native method in separate thread.. I'll get ouputMat from native method.. If I run the native method in separate thread I will get null ouputMat from thread which is returned from callThreadToDetect (). So I need to know how we can return the Mat object from callToThread () to Main thread.. (I.e inside onCameraFrame () ).. Thanks

Comment: ok. The code you provided gives black screen instead of camera preview and face detection, right?

Comment: Yes the above code gives black screen .. It's working fine when I call the native method in main thread (onCameraFrame ()) .

Comment: two questions: does your snippet compile? the `run()` implementation shouldn't be able to access the local variable `dispMat` in `callThreadToDetect()`, and the `run()` implementation uses two objects `inputMat` and `outputMat`. Where are they declared and initialized?

Comment: I'm able to compile it without any errors. `inputMat` is the one which has RGBA frame,  which is extracted from OpenCV camera and `outputMat` null frame which will contain the results after native method processing. I don't have exact idea about thread part. Can you please explain where does it go wrong? Thank you @nandsito

Comment: actually the thread is ok, but it's not parallelizing execution. The problem may be around `outputMat`, but it's still unclear to me where this object is managed

Comment: i am trying to help without compiling and testing code because setting up OpenCV is pretty hard. But if you provide me the entire project (in zip or tar.gz etc.) i can properly inspect and run the code

Comment: I have done android opencv as specified [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/technologies/mobile/opencv_tutorial_camera_preview.htm) and native dlib process [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927923/dlib-android-detection-of-face-landmark-is-slow)

Comment: You can refer this code, I have done exactly as specified in the link. and I'll be really happy if you come up with a solution for my problem. Thank you @nandsito

Comment: please provide your entire class